# How to check if a logged in user is in a role in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

Hello I'm somehow new in ASP.NET Core, I want to check, in the controller, if a logged-in user is in a certain role, to return the appropriate view. One view with the CRUD links, the other read-only.

I have two roles :

- The Manager "CanManage" (CRUD)
- The User "CanUse"

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Index() {

    bool isInrole = User.IsInRole("CanManage"); // First try
    bool isInrole = HttpContext.User.IsInRole("CanManage"); // Second try
    bool isInrole = User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "CanManage"); // Third try

    if (isInrole)
        return View(await _context.Etudiants.ToListAsync());
    return View("IndexReadonly", await _context.Etudiants.ToListAsync());
}
```

Each time the `bool` is `false`, any idea how to check the user roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution.

After some readings, it has been said that the Roles are somehow old school, and the Claims are the actual way! (If it makes sense...)

So, I did.

Had to do few steps to replace roles with claims.

1. Prepopulate the database with claims and users, inside the `ApplicationDBContext` class, in the `OnModelCreating` method

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    // Fluent API
    //...
    string MANAGER_ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    string BASIC_ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    var passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>();
    // Manager
    var managerName = "manager@email.com";
    var manager = new IdentityUser {
        Id = MANAGER_ID, // Primary key
        Email = managerName,
        NormalizedEmail = managerName.ToUpper(),
        UserName = managerName,
        NormalizedUserName = managerName.ToUpper(),
        EmailConfirmed = true,
    };
    manager.PasswordHash = passwordHasher.HashPassword(manager, "Pass_12345");

    // Basic user
    var basicname = "basic@email.com";
    var basic = new IdentityUser {
        Id = BASIC_ID, // Primary key
        Email = basicname,
        NormalizedEmail = basicname.ToUpper(),
        UserName = basicname,
        NormalizedUserName = basicname.ToUpper(),
        EmailConfirmed = true,
    };
    basic.PasswordHash = passwordHasher.HashPassword(basic, "Pass_12345");
    // Seeding the User to AspNetUsers table
    builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().HasData(manager, basic);

    builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().HasData(
        new IdentityUserClaim<string> { Id = 1, UserId = MANAGER_ID, ClaimType = AppClaimType.Manage, ClaimValue = "true" },
        new IdentityUserClaim<string> { Id = 2, UserId = BASIC_ID, ClaimType = AppClaimType.Basic, ClaimValue = "true" });
}
```

2. `Drop-Database` in the Package Manager Console (PMC) to start fresh
3. `Add-Migration Claims`, then `Update-Database`
4. An extra class just to reference the names of the claims and policies

```cs
public class AppClaimType{
    public const string Manage = "Manage Role";
    public const string Basic = "Basic Role";
}
public class AppPolicyName{
    public const string Management = "Management";
    public const string BasicUsage = "BasicUsage";
}
```

5. In the `Program.cs` made a policy

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    options.AddPolicy(AppPolicyName.Management,
        policy => policy.RequireClaim(AppClaimType.Manage, "true"));
});
```

6. Finally do the check in the Controller

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Index() {
    bool hasClaim = User.HasClaim(AppClaimType.Manage, "true");
    if (hasClaim)
        return View(await _context.Etudiants.ToListAsync());
    return View("IndexReadonly", await _context.Etudiants.ToListAsync());
}
```

Now the `bool` gets the correct value as expected, depends on the logged-in user (basic or manager)